# How come my disk utility shows that more space is being used compared to my terminal/OmnidiskSweeper? What is the hidden space DaisyDisk shows?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, terminal, storage

I have a 120 GB apple harddrive. Disk utility shows there is 119.36 GB being used but my terminal (as well as OmniDiskSweeper) only finds 104 GB. Even though I am administrator, I understand there is some files I don't have permission to see, but I don't know where those files are. In any event, I feel OmniDisk or terminal should still be able to know their there.

[Disk Utility image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoy61.png)

[Terminal output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFxmq.png)

DaisyDisk however, shows 11.4 GB of "hidden space". What could this be? How can I find out what is occupying that space?

I found a similar question where the user was able to fix this problem after disk utility found an error regarding an "invalid free block count", but my disk utility finds no errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to reindex spotlight before doing anything else.

> https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Select "Pecker Drive" when creating the exclusion, and then remove it from the list to reindex. You can check the progress by searching a term in Spotlight. It will tell you if it's indexing or not.

If that doesn't work, you can manually reindex using

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

After that if everything doesn't match up try this:

```
diskutil list
```

To find what your partition name is and then run this:

```
diskutil info /dev/disk0s2 (replace disk0s2 with the your corresponding partition)
```

What does the free space report as there?